# Dell Vostro 3550 has trackpad that fails intermitantly and doesn't use USB mouse

Tags: mouse, touchpad

In an attempt to work around the dead track pad, I had been using a USB mouse, but now that's stopped working too. I know it's not the mouse I'm using (works on other computers) and I'm pretty confident it's not the USB port (doesn't work in any of the three)

Comment: Welcome to Super User. This post seems incomplete, as if you submitted before you were done typing and including an actual question. Please use the [edit] feature to add more details and ask your question. Also, I wonder if the USB port also has intermittent issues with other devices?